# NIntegrate produces discontinuity, and converges slowly

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following functions:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f[x_] := Exp[- Sin[x]^2];
i[t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
   f[x1] f[x2]  Exp[-t^2 (x1 - x2)^2], {x1, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, {x2, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}];
```

But I notice that when I call `i[t]` at some specific points (e.g., `t[100]`), it complains:

```
NIntegrate: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the 
following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly 
oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.
```

while I believe these functions have no singularity except t=0, and is not oscillatory within the specified range. Also, when I plot the function (e.g., for t in (50, 150)), it shows discontinuities (shown in the figure below) and also produce the above warning, while, again, the function should be continuous. So what is causing the problem here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Split the second integration interval at the maximum to ensure sampling over the spike is sufficiently dense:

```
f[x_] := Exp[-Sin[x]^2];
i[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
   f[x1] f[x2] Exp[-t^2 (x1 - x2)^2],
    {x1, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
    {x2, -\[Pi]/2, x1, \[Pi]/2}]; (* <-- ! *)

Plot[i[t], {t, 50, 150}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f[x_] := Exp[-Sin[x]^2];
lst = Table[{t, 
    NIntegrate[
     f[x1] f[x2] Exp[-t^2 (x1 - x2)^2], {x1, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/
       2}, {x2, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]}, {t, 
    50, 150, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {2.11214, {{50, 0.0514137}, {55, 0.0467775}, {60, 0.0429099}, {65, 
   0.039631}, {70, 0.0368179}, {75, 0.034306}, {80, 0.0321265}, {85, 
   0.0302528}, {90, 0.0285856}, {95, 0.0270926}, {100, 
   0.0257478}, {105, 0.0245303}, {110, 0.0234228}, {115, 
   0.0224112}, {120, 0.0214835}, {125, 0.0206297}, {130, 
   0.0198413}, {135, 0.019091}, {140, 0.0184088}, {145, 
   0.0177677}, {150, 0.0170402}}}  *)
```

Let us define the interpolation function:

```
i = Interpolation[lst[[2]]];
```

and plot it together with the list:

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[lst[[2]]],
  Plot[i[t], {t, 50, 150}, PlotStyle -> Red]
  }]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Now within the interval t from 50 up to 150 you can work with the interpolation function as you like.

Have fun!

Comment: Great, but it doesn't seem to really solve the problem. What I need to do next is actually integrate i from 0 to infinity. I'm not sure if interpolating is realistic. I'm assuming it is NIntegrate that creates the discontinuity, is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: However, I tried again and found out that simply by adding the option `LocalAdaptive` seems to solve the issue.

Comment: Your $i(t)\propto 1/t$ as $t\to\infty$ and so your integral won't converge.

Comment: To be more specific: $\lim_{t\to\infty} t i(t)=e^{-1}\pi^{3/2} I_0(1)$.